# Can I import a table from SQL Server (=MS SQL) into a Python / Pandas data frame?

Tags: python, sql-server, dataset, dataframe, pandas

I am using `Matlab` and its '`datasets`', and `R` and its '`dataframes`'.

I am thinking of using Python but I need an equivalent data-storing format.
Extension 'Pandas' for Python has a class called dataframe which is similar.

**Now I would like to be able to send a query to a SQL Server and store the result of that query in a Panda Dataframe**

e.g.: `newDataFrame = GetDataFrameFromSQLServer('SELECT * from schema.table',sqlConnection)`

I had the impression that Pandas only talks to SQLite. Is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

I believe pandas can handle any reading from any DB API v2.0 compliant data source.  Have a look at `pandas.io.sql`([link](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/sql.py)) for a bunch of functions that facilitate this.

One thing to note, is that writing to a database requires a "flavor" where that flavor defaults to `sqlite`, but in the `write_frame` definition possible values are `{'sqlite', 'mysql', 'oracle'}`.